# SW Plugin changed from local to composer - how to update?

Tags: shopware6

We are using Shopware Paypal Plugin. Now we changed to local installation (uploaded plugin) to an installation via composer.

But `bin/console plugin:refresh` shows now this:

```
------------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ----------------- ----------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------- -------------
  Plugin                               Label                                                     Version       Upgrade version   Author                                                      Installed   Active   Upgradeable
 ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ----------------- ----------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------- -------------
  SwagPayPal                           PayPal-Produkte für Shopware 6                            3.5.0         5.3.0             Shopware                                                    Yes         Yes      Yes
 ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ----------------- ----------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------- -------------
```

Is there a "correct" way to fix this? Because from my point of view, the easiest is to just delete the plugin from the table and refresh again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A console command

`bin/console plugin:update -c SwagPayPal`

should do the job.

Since the code is already up-to-date thx composer, it will just update the database and run the migrations. If for any reason this doesn't work, you could go the hard way and re-install the plugin like this

`bin/console plugin:uninstall --keep-user-data -c SwagPayPal && bin/console plugin:install --activate -c SwagPayPal`

Answer (score 1):

I think it would not hurt to delete the entry and refresh, as you suggested.

Also it is worth mentioning that the is a column `managed_by_composer` in the table `plugin` which is important to set to `1` in your case. We did this manually via SQL in the past.